# How to show multiple divs with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use show() to show both an `<img>` and a `<a>`

Currently it will only show one or the other, whichever is called last. In the code below it'll be the `html(img).show()` because it comes after. Doing `$('.showimagediv').html(div,img).show();` has the same effect. Trying to combine the two statements into one variable:

```
var img = ($('<a />', {href    : this.getAttribute("data-permaLink"), 'class': 'permaLinkDiv'}),$('<img />', {src    : this.getAttribute("data-url"), 'class': 'fullScreenimg'}));
```

will only result in `<img>` showing up. Does anyone know how to show both at the same time?

```
  var imgToggle=false;
  $('.box').on('click', function() {
      var img = $('<img />', {src    : this.getAttribute("data-url"), 'class': 'fullScreenimg'});
      var div = $('<a />', {href    : this.getAttribute("data-permaLink"), 'class': 'permaLinkDiv'});
      if(imgToggle==true){
          $('.showimagediv').html(img).hide();
          imgToggle=false;
      }
      if(imgToggle==false){
          $('.showimagediv').html(div).show();
          $('.showimagediv').html(img).show();

          imgToggle=true;
      }

  })
  $('.showimagediv').on('click', function() {
      var img = $('<img />', {src    : this.getAttribute("data-url"), 'class': 'fullScreenimg'});
      var div = $('<a />', {href    : this.getAttribute("data-permaLink"), 'class': 'permaLinkDiv'});
      if(imgToggle==true){
          $('.showimagediv').html(img).hide();
          divToggle=false;
      }

  })
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the `innerHTML` of `.showimagediv` and then showing/hiding the `.showimagediv`. Try splitting the statement. First, set `html()` of `.showimagediv` and then `show()` or `hide()` the `img` or the `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add or remove css class with `display:none` to show your divs. It's very simply and a good way.

Example **CSS:** `.hide{display:none;}`

```
$('div').add('img').addClass('hide');  //or 
$('div').add('img').removeClass('hide');
```